# Image not fitting properly inside container and switching of image is not responding (Responsiveness)

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

I am trying to make a responsive website using **index.html and style.css file.**

I have **2 images under class photo (check div class="photo" code in html).**

Have a look at my two images

- [photo-small.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gTAd9.jpg)
- [photo-big.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rPCQA.jpg)

(Notice the difference in pixel and a  different text image being the same)

When I run my program in Google chrome **the image named as *photo-big.jpg* does not fit properly inside the container(div class="section header")** Why?

See the container in which it should fit:

[image]

See the image is not fitting inside the container:

[image]

When I change my browser **size to less than 960px image named as photo-small.jpg should load**, **but it doesn't load** but the thing is **photo-big resize itself some I don't know why is this happening?.**

See the image resize itself inside the container

- https://i.stack.imgur.com/gWMnN.jpg
- https://i.stack.imgur.com/JJb3n.jpg

If possible please explain me in detail.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.page {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.section {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.menu {
  background-color: black;
  height: 80px;
}

.header {
  background-color: #b2d6ff;
}

.content {
  background-color: #eaedf0;
  height: 600px;
}

.sign-up {
  background-color: #d6e9fe;
}

.feature-1 {
  background-color: #f5cf8e;
}

.feature-2 {
  background-color: #f09a9d;
}

.illustration img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.feature-3 {
  background-color: #c8c6fa;
}

.header {
  height: auto;
  justify-content: inherit;
  align-items: inherit;
}

.photo img {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  body {
    background-color: #f09a90;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 401px) and (max-width: 960px) {
  body {
    background-color: #f5cf8e;
  }
  .sign-up,
  .feature-1,
  .feature-2,
  .feature-3 {
    width: 50%;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 961px) {
  body {
    background-color: #b2d6ff;
  }
  .page {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  .feature-1,
  .feature-2,
  .feature-3 {
    width: 33.3%;
  }
  .header {
    height: 400px;
  }
  .sign-up {
    height: 200px;
    order: 1;
  }
  .content {
    order: 2;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
  <title>Responsive Desing</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="page">
    <div class="section menu"></div>

    <div class="section header">
      <div class="photo">
        <img src="images/photo-small.jpg" srcset="images/photo-small.jpg 1000w, images/photo-big.jpg 2000w" sizes="(min-width:960 px) 960px,100vw" />
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="section content">
      <div class="illustration">
        <img src="images/illustration-small.png" srcset="
                  images/illustration-small.png 1x,
                  images/illustration-big.png   2x
                " style="max-width: 500px" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="section sign-up">
      <img src="images/sign-up.svg" />
    </div>
    <div class="section feature-1">
      <img src="images/feature.svg" />
    </div>
    <div class="section feature-2">
      <img src="images/feature.svg" />
    </div>
    <div class="section feature-3">
      <img src="images/feature.svg" />
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

From [`object-fit` on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit):

> `cover`
>       The replaced content is sized to maintain its aspect ratio while filling the element’s entire content box. If the object's aspect ratio does not match the aspect ratio of its box, then the object will be clipped to fit.

The new style you'll need is

```
.header img {
  object-fit: cover;
}
```